# How to create Azure Policy to deny creating VM with RDP port enabled

Tags: azure, azure-policy

We have an azure policy in our subscription for Mandating creating Network Security Group:

[image]

I am trying to create an Azure Policy for Deny creating NSG with RDP port enabled:

[image]

We are getting warning for creating a Security Rule for inbound port 3389 after enabling the Policy as expected. But when we create VM, if we select the RDP port it was able to create the VM with the Network Security rule. We are not getting a warning when we create a VM.

What we are expecting is, We need a warning and the deployment of NSG should fail if we select the RDP port when we create a VM itself.

Could any one help me on this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can the following link: [Azure Policy – Deny inbound RDP from the internet](https://markgossa.com/2018/11/azure-policy-deny-inbound-rdp-from.html) be useful?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried this link also. But I didn't get the expected outcome (deployment of NSG should fail if we select the RDP port when we create a VM itself) from this link.